# AIML recognizing middle letter of any word

Tags: aiml

In aiml i am trying to make my bot recognize of middle letter of any word. for exemple if i ask "What is the middle letter of cat" then it should response "A" this is what code looks like

```
<category><pattern>MIDDLELETTER *</pattern>
<template>The middle letter of <star/> is: <srai>MIDDLEITEM <explode><star/></explode></srai></template>
</category>

<category><pattern>MIDDLEITEM * * *</pattern>
<template><srai>MIDDLEITEM <star index="2"/></srai></template>
</category>

<category><pattern>MIDDLEITEM *</pattern>
<template><star/></template>
</category>
```

The above code works fine in this scenario

```
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER CAT
ROBOT: The middle letter of CAT is: A
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER SKY
ROBOT: The middle letter of SKY is: K
```

But does not work properly in this case

```
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER ROMAN
ROBOT: The middle letter of ROMAN is: O
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER DCNOVAN
ROBOT: The middle letter of DCNOVAN is: C
```

I was expecting these kind of results

```
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER ROMAN
ROBOT: The middle letter of ROMAN is: M
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER DCNOVAN
ROBOT: The middle letter of DCNOVAN is: O
```

Also, what if if there are 8 letters in an word? i am expecting to make it work like

```
HUMAN: MIDDLELETTER ABSOLUTE
ROBOT: The middle letter of ABSOLUTE could be either O or L
```

What am i missing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the middle letter, you need to break up the word into individual letters and work out how long the word is. You can then use the length of the word to find the middle letter.

This method will work. For compatibility, I've assumed you have no math capabilities in your bot ie division. It works up to letters that are 11 letters long. For longer words, you should divide the word length by 2 to find the middle letter of a word.

```
<category>
<pattern>MIDDLELETTER *</pattern>
<template>
    <think>
        <set name="letternum">0</set>
        <srai>BreakUpWord <explode><star/></explode></srai>
        <condition name="letternum">
            <li value="1"><set name="middle"><get name="char1"/></set></li>
            <li value="2"><set name="middle"><get name="char1"/> or <get name="char2"/></set></li>
            <li value="3"><set name="middle"><get name="char2"/></set></li>
            <li value="4"><set name="middle"><get name="char2"/> or <get name="char3"/></set></li>
            <li value="5"><set name="middle"><get name="char3"/></set></li>
            <li value="6"><set name="middle"><get name="char3"/> or <get name="char4"/></set></li>
            <li value="7"><set name="middle"><get name="char4"/></set></li>
            <li value="8"><set name="middle"><get name="char4"/> or <get name="char5"/></set></li>
            <li value="9"><set name="middle"><get name="char5"/></set></li>
            <li value="10"><set name="middle"><get name="char5"/> or <get name="char6"/></set></li>
            <li value="11"><set name="middle"><get name="char6"/></set></li>
        </condition>
    </think>
    The middle letter of <star/> is <get name="middle"/>.
</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>BREAKUPWORD * *</pattern>
<template>
    <srai>IncreaseLetternum <star/></srai>
    <srai>BREAKUPWORD <star index="2"/></srai>
</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>BREAKUPWORD *</pattern>
<template>
    <srai>IncreaseLetternum <star/></srai>
</template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>INCREASELETTERNUM *</pattern>
<template>
    <think>
        <condition name="letternum">
            <li value="0"><set name="letternum">1</set><set name="char1"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="1"><set name="letternum">2</set><set name="char2"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="2"><set name="letternum">3</set><set name="char3"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="3"><set name="letternum">4</set><set name="char4"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="4"><set name="letternum">5</set><set name="char5"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="5"><set name="letternum">6</set><set name="char6"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="6"><set name="letternum">7</set><set name="char7"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="7"><set name="letternum">8</set><set name="char8"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="8"><set name="letternum">9</set><set name="char9"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="9"><set name="letternum">10</set><set name="char10"><star/></set></li>
            <li value="10"><set name="letternum">11</set><set name="char11"><star/></set></li>
        </condition>
    </think>
</template>
</category>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting unknown values using program-y

Comment: I guess Program-Y either doesn't use maps or doesn't know about the successor map. I've edited the code to be AIML 1 compatible.

Comment: It's working fine in program-ab.in program-y i checked the log and it's saying "No property for [char2]". I highly doubt it would work in program-y too as it supports predecessor, successor maps

Comment: Looks like Program Y possibly doesn't support allocating dynamic predicates. You may need to contact whoever supports Program-Y to resolve this. Is there any reason you are using Program-Y rather than the official Program-AB?

Comment: My friends talk with my chatbot and Program-Y has WhatsApp, telegram, Facebook clients so i choosed program-y

Comment: Okay. I've amended the code so it is now fully compatible with AIML 1.0